# pandas groupby to return dates in a dataset

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

Could someone give me a tip on how to use pandas groupby to find similar "days" in a time series dataset?

For example my data is (averaged daily values) a buildings electrical power and weather data, I am attempting to see if Pandas groupby can be used to find similar "days" both in electrical power usage and weather to a unique date in the time stamp of July 25th 2019.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bbartling/Data/master/stackoverflow_groupby_question.csv', parse_dates=True)

df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=True)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df_daily_avg = df.resample('D').mean()
```

What I am trying to find is like the top 10 or 15 most similar days in this dataset to the averaged temperature on that day of July 25th which is:

```
july_25_temp_avg = df_daily_avg.loc['2019-07-25'].Temperature_C

22.047916666666676
```

And averaged building power which is:

```
july_25_power_avg = df_daily_avg.loc['2019-07-25'].kW

52.658333333333324
```

If I use groupby, something like this below it strips away the time stamp index.

```
july25_most_similar =  df_daily_avg.groupby(['kW','Temperature_C'],as_index=False).Temperature_C.mean()
```

returns where it seems like most similar days are on the bottom:

```
kW  Temperature_C
0   9.316667    17.256250
1   9.433333    14.979167
2   9.616667    13.933333
3   9.683333    19.822917
4   10.116667   24.606250
... ... ...
360 58.741667   21.816667
361 61.250000   23.839583
362 61.633333   25.204167
363 62.483333   25.970833
364 63.808333   25.300000
```

Any tips greatly appreciated to return the timestamp/days that are most similar to July 25th Temperature & Power.

Also if it is possible to use more criteria than just `Temperature_C` is it possible to post an additional answer to use more weather data? For example the averaged power on July 25th and more weather data (beyond just `Temperature_C`) like `Wind_Speed_m_s    Relative_Humidity   Temperature_C   Pressure_mbar   DHI_DNI`?

Comment: why do you want to use `groupby`? I don't think it is the right method here. Your problem seems to be a neighboring problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would take this approach:

```
indx = df_daily_avg.sub(df_daily_avg.loc['2019-07-25']).abs()\
                   .sort_values(['Temperature_C', 'kW']).head(10).index.normalize()

df[df.index.normalize().isin(indx)]
```

Use diff and take the abs get the top then days sorted on 'Temperature_C' and 'kW' or some sort of metric that ranks the two.

Then get those index normalize them to a date and determine which rows in the original dataframe match retreived index.

Comment: Cool, I am going to have to study this one... I just changed the last part to df_daily, instead of df to return complete days.  like `df_daily_avg[df_daily_avg.index.normalize().isin(indx)]`

Comment: @HenryHub I thought the you wanted all the original rows not the aggregrated rows.

Comment: Yeah sorry maybe I should modify my question it was to return all "complete days" if that makes that are most similar to July 25, not the aggregated rows. Thats probably my bad for not explaining the problem. Does that seem Ok for what I modified? The results seem good to me at a glance

Comment: @HenryHub Sure go ahead.   Thanks!  Happy coding~

Comment: Thank you so much have a great day